# Aeson parse JSON with default value from previous parse

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I want to parse the following json:

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "align": "left"
  },
  "animals": [
    {
      "kind": "cat",
      "name": "Oscar",
      "align": "center"
    },
    {
      "kind": "dog",
      "name": "Max"
    }
  ]
}
```

Parse align:

```hs
data Align = Left | Center | Right

instance FromJSON Align where
  parseJSON (String "left")   = pure Left
  parseJSON (String "center") = pure Center
  parseJSON (String "right")  = pure Right
  parseJSON _ = fail "Expect one of [left, center, right]."
```

Parse defaults:

```hs
data BlockDefaults = BlockDefaults { align :: Align }

-- default value Center if key does not exist
blockDefaults :: BlockDefaults
blockDefaults = BlockDefaults { align = Center }

instance FromJSON BlockDefaults where
  parseJSON = withObject "defaults" $ \o -> BlockDefaults <$> o .:? "align" .!= align blockDefaults
```

Now I want to parse dog and cat.
If `align` does not exist (as in `dog`), it should take the value from defaults (`left`).
So `dog` should become `Dog{name="Max", align=Center}` and `cat` `Cat{name="Oscar", align=Left}`.

But how do I access the default align value in `parseJSON`?

```hs
-- pseudo parse code
instance FromJSON Animal where
  parseJSON = withObject "animal" $ \o ->
    Animal <$>
    o .: "kind" <*>
    o .: "name" <*>
    o .:? "align" .!= <DefaultValue> -- How to access value from defaults object?
```

I do not want to parse defaults for every animal again, so how can I access those defaults values parsed before?
Assume there are much more values in `defaults` and other `animals`.

---

So the animal parser code looks like this now:

```hs
parseAnimal :: BlockDefaults -> Value -> Parser Animal
parseAnimal defaults = withObject "animal" $ \o ->
  Animal <$> 
    o .: "kind" <*>
    o .: "name" <*>
    (
      BlockDefaults <$>
      o .:? "align" .!= align defaults
    )
```

Comment: How about `instance FromJSON (BlockDefaults -> Animal)`?

Comment: That sounds cool. Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My commented suggestion was to use `BlockDefaults -> Animal` as the instance.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
     build-depends: base, aeson
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Prelude hiding (Either(..)) -- This is why you don't name your constructors 'Left' and 'Right'
import Data.Aeson

data Align = Left | Center | Right
    deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Align where
  parseJSON (String "left")   = pure Left
  parseJSON (String "center") = pure Center
  parseJSON (String "right")  = pure Right
  parseJSON _ = fail "Expect one of [left, center, right]."

data BlockDefaults = BlockDefaults { align :: Align }

-- default value Center if key does not exist
blockDefaults :: BlockDefaults
blockDefaults = BlockDefaults { align = Center }

instance FromJSON BlockDefaults where
  parseJSON = withObject "defaults" $ \o -> BlockDefaults <$> o .:? "align" .!= align blockDefaults

data Animal = Animal { kind   :: String
                     , name   :: String
                     , aalign :: Align
                     }
    deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON (BlockDefaults -> Animal) where
    parseJSON = withObject "Animal" $ \o ->
        do k <- o  .: "kind"
           n <- o  .: "name"
           a <- o .:? "align"
           pure $ \def -> Animal k n (maybe (align def) id a)

main :: IO ()
main = print (decode "{ \"kind\": \"k\", \"name\" : \"n\" }" <*> Just blockDefaults :: Maybe Animal)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the `FromJSON` class, especially in such situations where parsing may depend on run-time data. With the freedom of declaring your own parsers, you can then easily define

```hs
parseAnimal :: BlockDefaults -> Value -> Parser Animal
```

---

Alternatively you can generalize `Animal` to a form that can be parsed without knowing the values of the defaults, e.g., just put a `Maybe` instead. For example:

```hs
data Animal_ a
  = Animal
      Kind
      Name
      a

type Animal = Animal_ Align

parseAnimal :: Value -> Parser (Animal_ (Maybe Align))
animalWithDefault :: BlockDefaults -> Animal_ (Maybe Align) -> Animal
```

Comment: This looks nice. Are there some disadvantages over using FromJSON as described by Thomas M. DuBuisson in the comment?
I don't like the second solution, because when there are more default values I get more and more Maybes.

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I can tell, there are two purposes to `FromJSON`: so it can be used by `encode` (instead of having to "run" the `Parser` by hand), and for generic deriving. The former is not essential, and the latter doesn't seem applicable here.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I also tried to implement the `instance FromJSON (BlockDefaults -> Animal)` solution but I don't know, how to get `Parser(BlockDefaults -> Animal)` out of `BlockDefaults -> Parser BlockBrightness`. Sorry I'm new to haskell.